# What is the meaning of single letters in IDA's functions window?

Tags: ida, tools

IDA's functions window, the window that lists all functions identified by IDA, has several columns represented by a single letter/character each. See example in attached picture.

The characters are: `R`, `F`, `L`, `S`, `B`, `T` and `=`

[image: functions window example]

What is the meaning of each column/character?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every column value can be either a dot or the same column character. Those columns are boolean and the column character stands for "True" while the dot stands for "False".

- R stands for "Returns" and is True (has an "R" in the column's value instead of a dot) if the function returns. Functions may not return and this requires special handling by IDA and the reverse engineer.
- F stands for "Far" and is true for functions that are far functions, or false otherwise.
- L stands for "Library" function, and is true for functions IDA recognised as library functions (usually using [FLIRT](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/tech/flirt/in_depth.shtml)).
- S stands for "Static" function.
- B stands for a E/R/BP stack frame based function. As part of IDA's analysis functions that use the xBP register for easier stack access are marked so.
- T stands for Type and indicates whether a function has type information assigned. Either manually or automatically by IDA using FLIRT.
- the equal sign (=) indicates the frame pointer is equal to the initial stack pointer.

All of those values can be manually accessible using the "Edit function" dialog (<kbd>alt+p</kbd>), like seen here:

[image: IDA edit function dialog]

This is also documented and can be found at [Hex-Rays website](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/586.shtml), with a shorter explanation.

Additionally, according to [Arnaud Diederen](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-letters-in-idas-functions-window#comment29115_18455):

> since 7.1, IDA also provides tooltips for those arguably cryptic single-letter columns. Just hover your mouse over the column header for a couple seconds, and the tooltip should appear.

Comment: shortcut is actually Alt-P, at least on Windows.

Comment: Since 7.1, IDA also provides tooltips for those arguably cryptic single-letter columns. Just hover your mouse over the column header for a couple seconds, and the tooltip should appear.